# django-sitetree sitetree_items always empty

Tags: django-sitetree

I've set up the tree using the GUI.
**This works well**:

```
{% load sitetree %}
{% sitetree_menu from "mainmenu"  include "trunk" %}
```

**This does NOT**:

```
{% load sitetree %}
{% for item in sitetree_items %}
    ITEM: {{ item.title_resolved }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

The for loop generates nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Versions:
django-sitetree 1.9.0
python 3.5.2
django 2.0

[tree admin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVn9f.png)